# Getting current object properties when calling an undeclared super method from abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance

Probably a very basic java question.

I have an abstract class, simplifying it:

```
public abstract class A{
  private String value = "A" ; // I want it undeclared, but set it for testing purpouse

  public String getValue(){
    return value ;
  }
}
```

Then I have a class extending it:

```
public abstract class B{
  private String value = "B" ;
}
```

So the problem I have is, when creating an instance of B through class A, and calling getValue(), it always return "A":

```
A b = new B();
b.getValue(); // returns "A"
```

How can I get B calling super method using his own properties without having to duplicate code? A it is currently too long, and it is extended to many different class that only differs by it properties values and all of them use the same methods that the super class has.

Thanks!

Edit:

Sorry, I wasn't so specific. I have a lot of properties, and some methods to deal with those properties. Extended class change those properties, but I want to use the super methods with the extended class instanced object without having to declare them twice. I'm working with servlets context atributtes if that helps.

Config.java

```
public abstract class Config {
    private String someValue1 ;
    ...
    private String someValuen ;

    public void export(ServletContext cxt){
        cxt.setAttribute("someValue1", someValue1);
        ...
        cxt.setAttribute("someValuen", someValuen);
    }
}
```

SomeConfig.java

```
public class SomeConfig {
    private String someValue1 = "something" ;
    ...
    private String someValuen = "something else" ;
}
```

SomeServlet.java

```
ServletContext cxt = getServletContext() ;
Config config = new SomeConfig();
config.export(cxt);
```

To make it clear, properties all have different names. I use them from jsp as: ${someValuen}

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it doesn't work is that only methods can be overriden - variable members are hidden instead (if you print `value` from your B class, it will be `"B"`).

For that specific example I would use a dedicated constructor (which I have made protected to prevent client classes from accessing it):

```
public abstract class A {
    private final String value;

    public A() { //for internal / testing use only
        value = "A";
    }

    protected A(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value ;
    }
}
```

Then B can simply call the relevant constructor:

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super("B");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Example with a `ConfigHolder`:

```
public class ConfigHolder {

    String value1;
    String value2;
    String value3;

    public ConfigHolder value1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        return this;
    }
    //same for other variables
}
```

Then in class A:

```
public abstract class A {
    private final ConfigHolder config;

    public A() { 
        this.config = new ConfigHolder()
                 .value1("value1")
                 .value2("value2");
    }

    protected A(ConfigHolder config) { 
        this.config = config;
    }

    public void export(ServletContext cxt){
        cxt.setAttribute("someValue1", builder.value1);
        ...
        cxt.setAttribute("someValuen", builder.valuen);
    }
}
```

And in B:

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(new ConfigBuilder()
                   .value1("value1InB")
                   .value2("value2InB"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Actually it is more complicated, A has a lot of standard properties, those are not gotten that specific way, an external object is passed to those methods, and the properties are used with this external object, so it is so many properties to do it that way. To be more specific, I'm passing a servlet context, and I am setting atributtes for each of the super class, so I want to declare the methods there, and have different configurations in the extended classes.

Comment: Maybe show us how you set and retrieve just one of those properties, so that it's clearer?

Comment: @JuanGarcia The alternatives I can think of are: (i) making all the variable protected - that way you can access and modify them from the subclasses (ii) add setters to the parent class and use them to modify the variables from the subclasses (iii) Use the builder pattern: Create a ConfigBuilder class which holds the variables and have your subclasses populate the ConfigBuilder the way they want.

Comment: @JuanGarcia I have added an example with an additional class which holds the configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I have use protected properties, as you advise, in the super class. For the extended class, I just assign properties values in the constructor. I've wrote my own answer if someone finds it useful. @assylias +1 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To do this: `A b = new B();` B must be a subclass of A

Besides, an abstract class can not be instantiated, ie can not create abstract class objects. The compiler will produce an error if you try to.

```
public abstract class A{
  private String value = "A" ;

  public String getValue(){
    return value ;
  }
}


public class B extends A{
    private String value ;
    public B(){
        value = "B";
    }
}
```

Now you can do `B notAbstractClass = new B();`

And when doing `notAbstractClass.getValue();` it must return "B"

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a simple way to do it with a constructor and changing the super class properties to protected (thanks to @assylias answer):
Config.java

```
public abstract class Config {
    protected String someValue1 ;
    ...
    protected String someValuen ;

    public void export(ServletContext cxt){
        cxt.setAttribute("someValue1", someValue1);
        ...
        cxt.setAttribute("someValuen", someValuen);
    }
}
```

SomeConfig.java

```
public class SomeConfig {
  public SomeConfig(){
    someValue1 = "something";
    ...
    someValuen = "something else";
  }
}
```